# Live streams created using the YouTube Data API are being marked as private

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

We are running into an issue where live streams created through the YouTube Data API are being marked private and locked without appeal after the stream, sometimes hours later.

We're using OAuth and the app has gone through the verification process and is verified.

Trying to see if anyone can provide answers to get us over this hurdle. This has been really frustrating as everything looks like it should be working, schedules are created, and the streams are being sent and watched, but are later marked private.

The email from YouTube says *spam*, *deceptive practices*, etc. But that seems to just be a generic response.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Your question is off-topic on SO (since it's not about programming). I recommend to address your issue directly to Google, through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/). SO users cannot help you since, it's unlikely that you could come up with a [mre]; but Google staff have all the info at their disposal to know what was/is happening with your live streams.

Comment: Hi @stvar - thanks for the notes. This is ultimately in the code and I'm not sure if there is some change we need to make in our code or how we are doing things that is causing issues. YT also points out to post here as their engineers monitor and answer questions in SO

Comment: Yes, I know that Google developer docs are mentioning Stack Overflow as a site monitored by Google engineers. But for the part of SO users answering questions in Google's name, I can state that, in my SO experience, I came across no such individuals. This was true well in the past (say 4-5 years ago, or even more), but nowadays that [claim made by Google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support) is contrary to reality (this being confirmed by other SO users too).

Comment: :) Google isn't my best friend at the moment...

Comment: Facing the same issue. Not able to raise issue to google-issue-tracker as they mention it for internal/partner usage.
@CaryMayo have you found the root cause for this?